# Swift 3 - AVPlayer - Playing a sound file and a video at the same time

Tags: swift, swift3, avplayer

I have a video, and that works perfectly.

```
let AVPlayerVC = AVPlayerViewController()

func setupCustomPlayer() {

    AVPlayerVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    AVPlayerVC.view.sizeToFit()
    AVPlayerVC.showsPlaybackControls = false
    self.view.addSubview(AVPlayerVC.view)

    let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://videourl")


    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
    AVPlayerVC.player = player
    AVPlayerVC.player?.play() 
}
```

Can I use AVplayer to play a sound file (mysoundfile.m4p) while video is playing? If not, what is the alternative solution for this.